# Unable to select radio button in MaterializeCSS

Tags: css, html, materialize

I am unable to select radio button after creating it in Materialize.

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s2">
        <input name="gender" type="radio" id="male" value="Male" />
        <label for="gender" style="font-size:12px;">Male</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s2">
        <input name="gender" type="radio" id="female" value="Female"/>
        <label for="gender" style="font-size:12px;">Female</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything worked fine for me in every browser.

Comment: yeah it seems correct but not working for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The labels' `for` attribute should match the ids on the checkboxes, not the name:

```
<label for="male">Male</label>
...
<label for="female">Female</label>
```